# File browser and bash ls give different results

Tags: debian, ls, shared-folders

Im using a NAS server with AFP service for quite some while. Now I switched finally to debian buster and wanted to use my photomaniging software again. go everything up and running.

A week ago I realized that several subfolder of the share where missing in my photolibrary. I tracked the problem down:

- accesing folders using the graphical File Manager in Gnome gives me all folders
- using termianl I can only see some of those
- trying to acces those by using cd and the right path will acces them

example: having the folders test/a/ test/b/ and test/c/
`bash:~/test/$ ls` will give me a/ and b/ but not c/
`bash:~/test/$ cd c` will acces folder c and show all the contents

any idea to solve that issue? best regards Leon

Comment: did you try to check with `ls -la` ?

Comment: Already tried that, i wasnt able to archive any diffrent results